# AudioContext not allowed to start in ToneJS (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Using ToneJS in Chrome, I frequently get this error message: "The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resume (or created) after a user gesture on the page."

For example, with the code below, I get this message every time I use ctrl-r or ctrl-f5 to refresh the page.

I can get it working again by typing `Tone.context.resume()` into the console, but that gets pretty repetitive. Why this is going on, and how can I stop it?

```
var keyToPitch = { "z":"C3", "s":"C#3", "x":"D3", "d":"D#3", "c":"E3", "v":"F3", "g":"F#3", "b":"G3", "h":"G#3", "n":"A3", "j":"A#3", "m":"B3", ",":"C4" }


var synth = new Tone.PolySynth(6, Tone.Synth, {
    "oscillator" : {
        "type": "sawtooth",
        "partials" : [0, 2, 3, 4],
        }
    }).toMaster();


 window.addEventListener('keydown', this.onkeydown)
 window.addEventListener('keyup', this.onkeyup)

function onkeydown(e){
   synth.triggerAttack(keyToPitch[e.key], Tone.context.currentTime)
}
function onkeyup(e){
    synth.triggerRelease(keyToPitch[e.key])
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears that Chrome is instituting a policy to [require user interaction to use AudioContext](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=807017) so that sites can't intrusively play audio without the user initiating it.

Fortunately, you are already using user input to trigger the audio via keydown and keyup events. Instead of calling `Tone.context.resume()` manually, you can hook up the events to initiate resume(), like this:

```
function onkeydown(e){
  Tone.context.resume().then(() => {
    synth.triggerAttack(keyToPitch[e.key], Tone.context.currentTime)
  });
}
function onkeyup(e){
  Tone.context.resume().then(() => {
    synth.triggerRelease(keyToPitch[e.key])
  });
}
```